# Unable to flash CWM recovery to GS3 over stock 4.1 with Heimdall

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-3, recovery-mode, heimdall

I want to root and upgrade to 4.1 a just-unboxed Samsung Galaxy S3.

After running the official OTA update with stock Samsung ROM, I tried to follow the tutorial [here](http://galaxys3root.com/galaxy-s3-root/how-to-root-galaxy-s3-on-linuxubuntu/) with openSUSE.

I installed Heimdall from YaST and run the tool with `--param` and `--recovery` options with the files I downloaded for rooting.

The problem is that after reboot I always get stock recovery.

Why doesn't it work with 4.1 OS but with 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the question I found the solution.

### Explanation

In Odin Mode, when the phone accepts a new recovery to be flashed, the original Samsung recovery of 4.1 ROM automatically does everything to avoid being flashed, that's actually re-flashing itself on reboot, just like a good ol' computer virus!

### Solution

Run Heimdall with `--no-reboot` flag, or if you are using Odin for Windows, uncheck the auto reboot checkbox.

When flashed, physically remove battery and disconnect USB power supply. Congratulations, you just have ClockworkMod recovery installed!!